# Error while I install the robotframework-retryfailed

Tags: python, pip, robotframework

How can I fix and install Robot Framework. I run the command pip install robotframework and get this.

```
C:\Users\vengalam>pip install -U robotframework-retryfailed
Collecting robotframework-retryfailed
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000020EE969F588>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/robotframework-retryfailed/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000020EE968F188>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/robotframework-retryfailed/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000020EE968FE88>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/robotframework-retryfailed/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000020EE968F808>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/robotframework-retryfailed/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000020EE969E648>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/robotframework-retryfailed/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement robotframework-retryfailed (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for robotframework-retryfailed
```

Package Installed in the machine with python

Python 3.7.4

C:\Users\vengalam>pip list

```
Package                        Version
------------------------------ ------------
bcrypt                         3.1.7
certifi                        2019.9.11
cffi                           1.13.2
chardet                        3.0.4
cryptography                   2.8
cx-Oracle                      7.2.2
et-xmlfile                     1.0.1
idna                           2.8
jdcal                          1.4.1
keyboard                       0.13.3
openpyxl                       2.6.2
paramiko                       2.6.0
pip                            19.0.3
pycparser                      2.16
pycryptodome                   3.9.4
PyNaCl                         1.3.0
requests                       2.22.0
robotframework                 3.1.2
robotframework-archivelibrary  0.4.0
robotframework-databaselibrary 1.2
robotframework-pabot           0.75
robotframework-requests        0.6.2
robotframework-seleniumlibrary 4.0.0a1
robotframework-sshlibrary      3.4.0
robotremoteserver              1.1
scp                            0.13.2
selenium                       3.141.0
setuptools                     40.8.0
six                            1.13.0
ssh2-python                    0.18.0.post1
urllib3                        1.25.3
xlrd                           1.2.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's some issue with pip try downloading files directly

Here - https://pypi.org/project/robotframework-retryfailed/#files

---

---

[image]

---

---

Install this zip file directly like so

```
pip install dummy_path\Downlaods\robotframework-retryfailed-0.2.0.tar.gz
```

**Note:** you need to use complete path of zip file after `pip install`